# Open external links in a new tab - Javascript

Tags: javascript

So after failing to do this without Javascript I decided to try and complete the job with javascript.

I am using the following code which I found on a similar question and even though it works on http://jsfiddle.net/zpFqQ/ it doesn't work on my live site.

```
    function externalLinks() {
  for(var c = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), a = 0;a < c.length;a++) {
    var b = c[a];
    b.getAttribute("href") && b.hostname !== location.hostname && (b.target = "_blank")
  }
}
;
externalLinks();
```

Any ideas why it might not work?

Thank you!

Comment: And `<a href="http://potato.com" target="_blank">asd</a>` didn't work in the HTML itself? Using javascript here is really overkill.

Comment: I am actually trying to make all the external links open in a new tab. Other than my website links.

Comment: If the fiddle works and your site doesn't, you must be doing something else to blow it up.

Comment: Hmm. I agree with @lincolnk it might be somewhere else on your site that's causing the issue. Not really an answer, but if you were using JQuery, you could simplify your whole JS code down to one little line: `$("a").attr("target", "_blank");` inside the `document.ready()` of JQuery